# How to create a dynamic array using new C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to initialize an array of integers dynamically, since the size of the array changes based on input.
The program is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int* list = createList("dis.bin");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }
}
```

With `createList()` function as written:

```
int* createList(const char* file_name)
{
    int counter = 1;
    int* inst{};
    FILE* myFile = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (myFile == nullptr)
    {
        printf("\nFile not opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; !(feof(myFile)); i++)
    {
        fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, myFile);
        inst = new int[counter];
        inst[i] = x;
        printf("%08x #%-4d |   Int equiv: %-12d |   Bin equiv: %s\n", x, counter, inst[i], ToBinary(inst[i], 0));
        counter += 1;
        x = 0;
    }

    return inst;
}
```

`createList` reads from a `.bin` file (basically containing an array of bytes) and inserts each pair of 4 bytes to an item in the array `inst`. I do this by allocating a new amount of space for the array based on the `counter` variable. (So whatever value counter is becomes the size of the array with `inst = new int[counter]`) Then I set the contents of the array at the given index `i` equal to x (the pair of bytes read) I would assume it is working correctly in `createList` at least, because of the `printf` statement which is printing each element in `inst[]`.

However, when I call `createList("dis.bin")` in main and assign it to the variable `int* list`, I try to iterate through each value. But this just prints out one uninitialized value (-842150451, if you're curious). So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

I should mention that I am NOT using vectors or really any std container. I am just working with arrays. I also am using `printf` for specific reasons.

Comment: Also note that `inst = new int[counter];` will overwrite any previous address stored in `inst` and that memory will be leaked. You won't be 'appending' a new `int` to an old list, just creating a new (mostly uninitialized) list.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so am I supposed to get the counter variable first, and then create the array? Then iterate through the file again to set the values?

Comment: You could do that. Or like vector does have a capacity and size and allocate more than needed and when the vector is full reallocate to a larger size perhaps 2 times as big and copy the old data to new location.

Comment: won't `sizeof(list)` always be 4 (or 8 depending on architecture) since `list` is a pointer?

Comment: @Andy That is correct. The function will need to somehow return the size of the created array (as a second argument, maybe: `int& size`).

Comment: If this is really C++, then you should try to stick to that language and all the wonderful tools it gives you.

Comment: @Andy the purpose of not using certain C++ standard tools is to educate myself. I clarified my restrictions so I expected that to suffice.

Comment: Write your code with `std::vector`, then if `std::vector` is not available, roll your own version such that your main code need not be changed. By the way your `for` loop is broken, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/).

Comment: @EthanR -- *I am just working with arrays* -- No you're not -- you're working with pointers and dynamically allocated memory, absolutely no different than what `std::vector` is doing.  A `vector` is not using magic -- it is using `new` to allocate the memory, but it is already written to behave correctly.  That's the real difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No need to be pedantic. By “I am just working with arrays”, I thought that clearly outlined my choice to not use vectors.

Comment: There is a difference between arrays and pointers.  A pointer is not an array, and that is an important difference.  Why not attempt to write a vector *class*, instead of having `new[]` and `delete[]` around the codebase like that?  You would learn far more doing things that way than having those calls not encapsulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tagged as C++, but OP is showing C code and says they need it in C, so I will show this in C... but the pre-req is that it uses `new` and not `malloc`

```
int* createList(const char* file_name, int& count)
{
    // initialize count, so that way if we return early, we don't have invalid information
    count = 0;

    // open the file ad "READ" and "BINARY"
    FILE* myFile = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (!myFile)
    {
        printf("\nFile not opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // calculate how many 4-byte integers exist in the file using
    // the file length
    fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    count = ftell(myFile) / sizeof(int);
    rewind(myFile);
    
    // allocate the memory
    int* returnData = new int[count];

    // read in 4-byte chunks to our array until it can't read anymore
    int i = 0;
    while (fread(&returnData[i++], sizeof(int), 1, myFile) == 1);

    // close the file
    fclose(myFile);

    // return our newly allocated data
    return returnData;
}

int main()
{
    int count;
    int* myInts = createList("c:\\users\\andy\\desktop\\dis.bin", count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", myInts[i]);
    }
    // don't forget to delete your data. (another reason a vector would be better suited... no one remembers to delete :)
    delete myInts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you--but the question was specifically asked with `new` in mind, which I believe is only a part of C++.

Comment: There is no `realloc` type stuff in C++ because they expect you to use C++ constructs like `vector` for these things. Sure, it's possible to roll your own... but you're missing the point of using C++.

Comment: No, you simply write the reallocation yourself. You allocate a new array larger than the current. You copy the current to the newly allocated array, and you `delete[]` the old one (the one that was current but no longer is) and keep going.

Comment: fixed it so it uses `new` @EthanR

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- true, but... would *you* do that? :)

Comment: @Andy Well isn't the vector construct fairly inefficient? As far as I'm aware, there are more efficient alternatives should you choose you make your own. Several companies I know of use their own form of vectors for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: @EthanR -- all depends on how you use them. Of course you will take some sort of hit on efficiency, it is a container data structure. But the amount of time it saves you on safety, readability and maintainability is well worth it.

Comment: @EthanR *Well isn't the vector construct fairly inefficient?* -- No.  Where did you get this information?

Comment: @Andy -- Where is the efficiency hit in vector?  The only thing would be that vector initializes its data.  With the advent of move semantics, plus vector uses `placement-new`, plus the mere fact that the compiler's implementation of `std::vector` is as fine-tuned as possible (written by very intelligent C++ library writers), the "fairly inefficient" point is really not justified by the OP.  If the question is if vector is the best container for the job, that is a different story.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- I mean on a scale of pico-seconds, something that humans wouldn't notice. When allocating a straight-up array of `int` and filling it vs. creating a `vector` and pushing `int`s on to it. I'm sure the array method will be slightly faster if you had to do fill over a million integers. I am in your camp, though. I would choose `vector` 10 times out of 10 if given a challenge like this.

Comment: @Andy - yes, there are two decades worth of C++ out there that do just that. STL just didn't magically appear and Ex pos facto rewrite all the C++ that came before. While all new code going forward would be wise to use STL, it is just as important to know how to handle manual memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. The usage of `new` was misinterpreted by me. For whatever reason, I thought that each time I allocated new memory for `inst` that it would just be appending new memory to the already allocated memory, but this is obviously not the case. If I wanted to simulate this, I would have to copy the contents of the array after each iteration and add that to the newly allocated memory. To solve this, I waited to allocate memory for `inst` until after the file iteration was complete.
2. As Andy pointed out, `sizeof(list) / sizeof(int)` would not give me the number of elements in `list`, since it is a pointer. To get around this, I created a new parameter `int &read` for the `createList()` function in order to pass the number of items created.

With these points, the new function looks like this and works as intended:

```
int* createList(const char* file_name, int &read)
{
    int counter = 1;
    FILE* myFile = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (myFile == nullptr)
    {
        printf("\nFile not opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; !(feof(myFile)); i++)
    {
        fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, myFile);
        printf("%08x #%-4d |   Int equiv: %-12d |   Bin equiv: %s\n", x, counter, x, ToBinary(x, 0));
        counter += 1;
    }

    int* inst = new int[counter];
    read = counter;
    rewind(myFile); // rewind to beginning of file

    for (int i = 0; !(feof(myFile)); i++)
    {
        fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, myFile);
        inst[i] = x;
        x = 0;
    }
    
    return inst;
}
```

With main changed a bit as well:

```
int main()
{
    int read;
    int* list = createList("dis.bin", read);
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }
}
```

As for the comments about the invalidity of `!(feof(myFile))`, although helpful, this was not a part of my question and thus not of my concern. But I will source the solution to that for the sake of spreading important information:  [Why is "while ( !feof(file) )" always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/10871073)

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the file system using C-style, so I didn't quite know how to grab the number necessary without reading the file twice. I just hacked together the solution quickly.

Comment: You forgot to deallocate the memory, thus leaks memory.  Note that in a non-trivial program, this all becomes a maintenance headache.